# Nuget.exe Custom assemblies repository

Tags: nuget

How can I specify custom repository by running nuget.exe? 
Makes sense that it could be specified somehow in repositories.config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet.exe supports a **-Source** command line option for specifying the package repository to use. If this is not specified then the package repositories defined in the **%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config** file are used.

If you type **NuGet.exe help** you can view the command line options or alternatively take a look at the online [NuGet.exe Command Line Reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference) for more information.